# Basic dyplr functions give an error: "check_dots_used"

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Trying to figure out why I am getting this error (never seen it before, google is no help):

*Error in check_dots_used(action = warn) : unused argument (action = warn)*

I am getting the error for the very basic trial below, but also for group_by/count, but not filter or select.

```
 x <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
 y <- runif(5)
 tibble(x, y)
Error in check_dots_used(action = warn) : unused argument (action = warn)
```

Comment: This may be resolved simply by updating the packages. I recall seeing it in the past. Those lines return no error for me at the moment.

Comment: I too, see no errors on those lines.  I would re-install the `tidyverse`.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem: [urganmax](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7821090/urganmax)'s solution to update to `ellipsis-0.3.1` in a comment did it for me. Moving this as an answer so it is easier to find.

I had to update/re-install tidyverse and the ellipsis package explicitly:

```
install.packages("tidyverse")
install.packages("ellipsis")
```

Then restart your session and library your packages (or unload and reload your packages).

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty certain that your version of the `ellipsis` package (part of the tidyverse) is out of sync with the other tidyverse packages you have. `update.packages()` should work ... (if you want to live dangerously, `update.packages(ask=FALSE)` to update all packages without asking for confirmation for each one).

From the [tidyverse NEWS file](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/news/index.html):

> All functions that take ... have been instrumented with functions from the ellipsis package to warn if you’ve supplied arguments that are ignored (typically because you’ve misspelled an argument name) (#573).

Comment: For me, updating `tidyverse` doesn't suffice, explicitly updating `ellipsis-0.3.1` does it.