# skimr(iris) generates error in check_dots_used when printing in linux RStudio console

Tags: r, r-markdown, skimr

When I run the default skimr command in the console on a linux RStudio server I get the following partial output and error:

library(skimr)
skim(iris)

── Data Summary ────────────────────────
Values
Name                       iris
Number of rows             150
Number of columns          5

---

Column type frequency:
factor                   1
numeric                  4

---

Group variables            None
**Error in check_dots_used(action = warn) : unused argument (action = warn)**

However, the same code will run just fine when I knit it in an RMarkdown document.

[image: RMarkdown Output]

The same code will also run fine on my Mac OSX laptop instance of RStudio, both in the console and an RMarkdown document.

I can assign the output of the skimr command and View the assigned output object just fine on the server instance:

out <- skim(iris)
View(out)
class(out)
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZczJ.png) "skim_df"    "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"

but print(out) generates the same error again

Here's the sessionInfo.

> sessionInfo()

R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)

Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)

Running under: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)

Matrix products: default

BLAS/LAPACK: /usr/lib64/R/lib/libRblas.so

locale:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZczJ.png) LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8
[6] LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZczJ.png) stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZczJ.png) skimr_2.1.2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZczJ.png) Rcpp_1.0.2       rstudioapi_0.13  knitr_1.31       magrittr_1.5     tidyselect_1.1.0 R6_2.3.0         rlang_0.4.10     fansi_0.4.0      stringr_1.4.0
[10] dplyr_1.0.4      tools_3.5.1      xfun_0.20        utf8_1.1.4       cli_2.3.0        DBI_1.0.0        withr_2.4.1      htmltools_0.3.6  ellipsis_0.2.0.1
[19] yaml_2.2.0       rprojroot_1.3-2  assertthat_0.2.0 digest_0.6.18    tibble_3.0.6     lifecycle_0.2.0  crayon_1.3.4     tidyr_1.1.2      purrr_0.3.4
[28] repr_1.1.3       base64enc_0.1-3  vctrs_0.3.6      evaluate_0.12    glue_1.4.2       rmarkdown_1.10   stringi_1.2.4    compiler_3.5.1   pillar_1.4.7
[37] backports_1.1.2  generics_0.1.0   jsonlite_1.6     pkgconfig_2.0.2

Comment: After rereading the [README](https://github.com/ropensci/skimr) again, I noticed the `skim_without_charts()`  command and thought that might be a fix. Alas, it generates the same output and error for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `options(skimr_strip_metadata = FALSE)`. It's due to something related to the {pilar} package.
https://github.com/ropensci/skimr/issues/641

Also please update the ellipsis package. See this answer.
[Basic dyplr functions give an error: "check_dots_used"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62998999/basic-dyplr-functions-give-an-error-check-dots-used)

I don't know why  doing it in rmarkdown would work when the console doesn't, unless somehow a different version of the package is loading.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. Unfortunately, I didn't get any change in the behavior... same error still.

Comment: I updated ellipsis package from 0.2.0.1 to 0.3.1 and that seemed to do it. Thank for your continued effort to help!

Answer (score 0):

I used to have a similar situation where skim_without_chart will return an error **could not find function "skim_without_charts".**

The solution I used is to first call skimr before calling skimm_without_charts like skimr::skim_without_charts(penguins) [image]
That solves the problem for me.